# How to prove that $\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{MSA}]=\sigma^2+\frac{n}{a-1}\sum_{i=1}^{a}(\mu_i−\mu)^2$.

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I need to prove that the expected value of MSA is equal to the expression to the right. Where MSA is the mean square of a factor a. The equations are easier to understand in the link of the images.

$$ \mathrm{MSA} = \frac{\mathrm{SSA}}{\mathrm{gla}}, \qquad \mathrm{SSA} = \sum_{i} (\bar{Y}_i - \bar{y})^2 $$

$$ \mu = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{i=1}^{a} \mu_i, $$

$$ \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{MSA}]=\sigma^2+\frac{n}{a-1}\sum_{i=1}^{a}(\mu_i−\mu)^2. $$
 asume the experiment is balanced.

Comment: Please write the complete question (defining your expressions) and try to include your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I edited your question so that formulas are more readable. Hope this is to your liking.

Comment: Sangchul Lee thanks.

Comment: Please show your work. Presumably you are working with a linear model, in which case what is your model exactly?

Comment: what is the MSA expression, what is SSA and what is gla ?

Comment: The terminology 'factor' is likely incorrect. I think you want MS(Factor A) where $a$ is the number of _levels_ of Factor A and the $\mu_i$ are the population means for the $a$ levels. Also, my guess is that $\mu = \frac 1 a \sum_i \mu_i.$

Comment: @BruceET you are right. Would you please help me with the solution? Thanks